# Is it "the fine arts" or just "fine arts"?

Tags: capitalization, definite-articles, zero-article

Is it "the fine arts" or just "fine arts"?

Also, do I capitalize anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of the time, it is the fine arts.  The only exception is when fine arts is a modifier on a noun, such as:

> He has a fine arts degree.

Also, it isn't capitalized unless it is part of a title (because that follows its own rules that overrule other rules):

> Jen Oak, Director, Fine Arts.